# Solr 4.7.1 uploading CSV Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field id

Tags: csv, solr, solr4

I'm new to solr (4.7.1).  I unzip the solr code and copied the schemaless example to its own directory.  I then used start.jar passing it -Dsolr.solr.home=" to the new location.  Jetty came up and everything appears to be working on that front.

Now I wanted to upload/update a csv file to it.  Here's what I used:

`curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update/csv --data-binary @c:\solrschemaless\data.csv -H "Content-type:text/csv; charset=utf-8"`

I received the following:

```xml
<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">400</int>
    <int name="QTime">0</int>
  </lst>
  <lst name="error">
    <str name="msg">Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id</str>
    <int name="code">400</int>
  </lst>
</response>
```

The csv file has a column named XXXXID.  I changed to "id", "id_s", "id_i" but still getting the same error.  There are a lot of post on SO and elsewhere but thus far I didn't see one for the schemaless model.

**EDIT:**  I reduced down my csv file to this:

```
id,Contact,Address,Focus,Type
 2,97087,1170,NULL,1
```

and I'm still getting the same error message of missing mandatory uniqueKey.

I'm on Windows 8.

Any ideas?

Comment: @sidgate he is running in schemaless mode ... so there is no schema :)

Comment: Would you paste a sample CSV somewhere?

Comment: @cheffe Please see my Edit.  Thanks for looking into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  For some reason the column id cannot be the first column on the list.  When I change

```
id,Contact,Address,Focus,Type
2,97087,1170,NULL,1
```

to this

```
foo,id,Contact,Address,Focus,Type
bar,2,97087,1170,NULL,1
```

it works.